# Add "Rubber Band" effect in android while changing background of application

Tags: android, background, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling, rubber-band

I am working on the application in which:

User will have a control to change the background and text (multiples) by doing horizontal swipe for BG and vertical swipe for text. In this case, if I am changing BG, text should remain constant and if I am changing text then BG should remain constant.

Also, I want to add **`Rubber Band effect`**  like in iOS when user changes Text and BG.

I am thinking of [**`twoway-view`**](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) library to support for vertical and horizontal scrolling. But how to use this library in my case?

Any idea/solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

twoway-view implements an AdapterView that can scroll vertically or horizontally, but not both at the same time. It wouldn't work in your case.

I would use a ViewPager in which each fragment:

1. Shows a certain background
2. Lets the user select the text through swipe up and down gestures.

To obtain a rubber band effect, just add a [BounceInterpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/BounceInterpolator.html) to the animation that moves the text up & down. In the ViewPager you could get a similar effect applying a custom [PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html).

Comment: Please have a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561357/how-to-achieve-a-bounce-elastic-animation-effect-in-viewpager). You have mentioned a similar approach in your answer in general terms. I would appreciate it if you could provide a detailed solution with code.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a combination of GestureDetector, SimpleOnGestureListener and TranslateAnimation on your layout. This can be fairly involved but you can find a [Translation example at this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374823/android-animate-my-relative-layout-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-using-tr) and [GestureDetector/SimpleOnGestureListener example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272821/vertical-and-horizontal-gestures-in-android) Hopefully you can figured out how to adapt the code to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library for the Rubber Band effect: [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.