# What is the best way to achieve an elastic / bounce animation effect in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-pagetransformer

I want to display a [`ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with a bounce / elastic sliding effect. I suppose that this is possible using some combination of a [`PageTransformer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html) and a [`BounceInterpolator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/BounceInterpolator.html).

What I do not know is ***how***. Thus far I have been unable to achieve this.

A typical example of a `PageTransformer` would be something like this:

```
public class TypicalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            view.setAlpha(1);
            view.setTranslationX(0);
            view.setScaleX(1);
            view.setScaleY(1);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
            // Fade the page out.
            view.setAlpha(1 - position);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                    + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, how do we bring an [`Interpolator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) (of any kind) into the picture here? **Where do we get the [`Animation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) object for the `ViewPager`'s animation from, so as to set an `Interpolator` to it?**

I have already referred to the following posts:

- [**android VIewpager How to achieve the bound effect**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13759862).
- [**How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082171)
- [**Add “Rubber Band” effect in android while changing background of application**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23753604).

The third post has an answer that mentions this very approach, but does not provide any detail as to how.

Does anyone know exactly how do we go about combining a `BounceInterpolator` with a `PageTransformer`? This ***seems*** to be an organic and coherent approach to this problem, but is it even possible at all? Or is there another logical solution for this?

**References:**

- [Customize the `ViewPager` with `PageTransformer`](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer).

**N.B:**

It *should* be possible to achieve an elastic / bounce animation effect  simply by combining an `Interpolator` and a `PageTransformer`, and without having to extend the `ViewPager`. Other approaches are also welcome, but please provide a detailed solution with code, not just an outline.

Comment: will this example hold good ?  https://github.com/chenupt/SpringIndicator

Comment: Customize the viewpager and in ontTouchEvent scale the listview using a set of ValueAnimators being played sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that `PageTransformer` is the best way to achieve mentioned effect. Note, that such transformations will be the same in both swiping directions, since received position gives no idea about if we swipe left-to-right or vice versa. And probably you don't want bouncing of two opposite sides of view, but only one, to which pull is applied. And the second, and IMO more important, `PageTransformer` framing is driven by user's gesture, not by stable system clock. And as result - we can't control duration of fade phase (phase when user has released his/her finger) and achieve smooth behavior (because in general ticks are delivered with non-monotonically changed position, that depends heavily on touch velocity).

So, it would be much better to use standard `ValueAnimator` API, that will be triggered by `OnPageChangeListener`. Of course in this case we have another caveats but this approach seems to be more promising.